# Keyboard acts as if the Command key is depressed 100% of the time

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro

I've got a 2010 macbook air that works fine in all respects except for the keyboard acts as if the command key is depressed all the time. The key does not appear to be physically depressed however.

Is this a hardware problem, and if so is it possible to replace the keyboard, or a single key on the macbook air? Or perhaps is their a way to disable a key in the OS and re-map it to another key, or just one of the command keys.

Comment: Yes and NO :) It is hardware problem and you can not replace single key.

Comment: Does your MBA has 2 cmd key's? and are they both broken?

Comment: @FLY Well I am not sure which one is broken, or if both are, or if there is some short circuit in the keyboard as a whole. Neither appears to be depressed, but osx acts as if the cmd key is down. I am assuming only one is the problem and disabling it would be the simple (read free) solution to the problem.

Comment: Does the problem persist after rebooting? When you use the keyboard viewer, is the command key shaded?

Comment: The problem does persist after reboot, in fact the machine as has been re-imaged.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this fixes it but It's worth a try:

Open the on screen keyboard viewer and click on the cmd key:

[image: keyboard]

When I have the cmd key pressed down it now becomes unpressed.

If you're not sure where you can find the on screen keyboard viewer it can either be [here](http://gigaom.com/2008/09/24/mac-101-get-an-onscreen-keyboard-in-osx/) or you have to enable "Show Keyboard & Character Vieuwers in menu bar" under your keyboard settings. And then click on show keyboard viewer in under the icon in the menu bar. Or just google how to show the on screen keyboard ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling it from the keyboard preference pane:

[image]

Or use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4Macbook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>disablecommand</name>
    <identifier>disablecommand</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <!--<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::COMMAND_R</autogen>-->
  </item>
</root>
```